# What happens when a Favoured Soul gains a Domain?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

There are multiple ways for a *Favoured Soul* to gain a *Domain*. For example, the *Divine Oracle* is an easily entered Prestige Class, and on its first level:

> **Oracle Domain**: Upon adopting the divine oracle class, the character gains access to the *Oracle domain*. The character gains the granted power associated with the domain (+2 caster level for divination spells), and can choose the spells in that domain as her daily domain spells.

This description is obviously tailored for a *Cleric*; a *Favoured Soul*, however, does not have *daily domain spells*.

---

I have failed to find, so far, what happens when a *Favoured Soul* gains a domain with regard to the domain spells. I surmise one of 3 effects are possible:

- Nothing,
- The domain spells are added to the *Favoured Soul* accessible spells,
- The domain spells are added to the *Favoured Soul* **known** spells.

I have seen many builds using the latter [and even advice to seek Domains out](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/10262/is-there-a-favored-soul-handbook), which is of course the most favorable reading, but I have failed so far to find any rule.

Have I missed the rule? Or it this up to the DM?

---

*For completeness, here is a short list of Prestige Classes granting extra domains, in cases there are differences per book:*

- *Complete Divine: Church Inquisitor, Contemplative, Divine Oracle, Sacred Exorcist*,
- *Draconomicon: Dracolyte*,
- *Player's Guide to Faerun: Divine Disciple*,
- *Races of the Dragon: Singer of Concordance*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the domain spells to your class spell list, but you don't automatically know them. You have to allocate some of your limited supply of spells-known if you want to learn them.

From Complete Divine p.20:

> If a noncleric enters a prestige class that allows access to a domain, the character still gains access to the domain. She can use the granted power bestowed by the domain normally.
>
> If she memorizes spells like a druid, paladin, or ranger, then she can simply choose to memorize one of that domain’s spells instead of one of her usual spells, but never more than one domain spell of each level.
>
> If she is a spellcaster who keeps a spellbook as a wizard does, then she must find or purchase a scroll of that spell and pay the usual price to scribe the spell into her spellbook. In cases where the spell is only divine the wizard may scribe a divine scroll into his book. The wizard then may memorize one domain spell of each level each day.
>
> If the noncleric is a spontaneous caster like a sorcerer or favored soul, then she may select a domain spell to add to her spells known whenever she would have an option to choose a new known spell. A sorcerer does not get to exceed his normal limit of spells known. Once the domain spell is known, the sorcerer may cast it freely.
>
> Unless the prestige class specifies otherwise, such spells are considered arcane spells when cast by arcane spellcasters.

Comment: This covers *Church Inquisitor*, *Contemplative* and *Divine Oracle* for certain. I would probably extend the ruling to prestige classes from another book, such as *Divine Disciple* (PGtF), *Dracolyte* (Draconomicon), *Sacred Exorcist* (BoED) and *Singer of Concordance* (RotD); but just for completeness would you know if there are exceptions for them?

Comment: @MatthieuM. As the first book to offer bonus domains as a general thing, and having a large section about the rules for extra domains, *Complete Divine* is reasonably considered the primary source on the subject. Even if another source said something else, unless it was explicitly making an exception for a particular class (see each class’s description), it would conflict with *Complete Divine*, the primary source, and should therefore be ignored. Note that *Draconomicon* is earlier, however, and dracolyte uses its own particular rule (an exception for that class). They are slightly different.

Comment: @KRyan: Thanks! I hadn't thought about checking the publication dates of the different books. Looks like extra domains are not necessarily as useful to a Favoured Soul as Internet claims (unless they give access to non-Cleric spells, like... Anyspell, etc...).

Comment: @MatthieuM. Sorry, I did slightly mispeak; *Draconomicon* is earlier than *Complete Divine*, and the dracolyte **does** have particular (exceptional) rules for itself rather than using any general rules (which didn’t exist at the time). See edited comment. And *Book of Exalted Deeds* is also earlier, but sacred exorcist is in *Complete Divine*, not *Book of Exalted Deeds*. No prestige class in *Book of Exalted Deeds* grants a bonus domain.

Comment: @KRyan: The Draconomicon's rule is interesting. Given the wording it seems the *Favoured Soul* would gain the ability to cast the spells (1/day for each spell-level), but only as long as this is its only domain :x